# Coding path to file when it is called using registry and context menu

Tags: c#, registry, arguments, contextmenu, console-application

In my **c# console application**, which takes string as arguments, 
I have a context menu item for images, that calls `"myexe.exe %1"`, so path to file becomes argument for application. Even if path to file contains spaces, when I watch, what argument my application takes, I can see something like `"VISUAL~3/...."` *(it is example when path to file contains "visual stuido", it has space)*.

But my application should understand how many arguments are given, so if it is called from context menu, everything is ok, because result argument has no spaces.

But I need call **exe file** from other application and give string arguments with spaces too. When I just give argument with spaces, my application splits it, so I don't know how to code spaces in argument to give it to exe file, like context menu does. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should double quote your command lines arguments, e.g.,

```
string args = "\"arg 1\" \"arg 2\"";
```

Comment: it is not absolutely that I wanted, but I changed my code, so it is solved, thank you

Comment: @user1495756 - If this isn't what you wanted, why did you accept it as the answer, that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Both, the **Path** AND the **Variable** must be quoted separately, e.g., **"myexe.exe" "%1"**. That will prevent an argument with spaces to produce an invalid path:

"myexe.exe %1" becomes "myexe.exe ar gu ment", an **"** executable that makes no sense **"**, while

**"myexe.exe" "%1"** becomes "myexe.exe" "*ar gu ment*", an **"** executable **" "** *with a single argument* **"**.